# Pass Map as the param of aidl method

Tags: android, dictionary, android-service, aidl

I need to pass a **scalable** type param through an AIDL method. I'm now using **Map**, like `void notify(in Map payload)` in the aidl file. But I'm wondering if it is a good solution? Because the Map is a general type, so I should specify the Map's key for others when I share this interface with partner's project.

Comment: keys? what keys are you talking about?

Comment: The **key** and value pairs in Map

Comment: and what is your problem actually? i know how `java.util.Map` works but what keys have to do with AIDL?

Comment: The Map is not a self-documenting type. So I'm asking is there any different approach to make this aidl interface much more clear to the client

Answer (score 1):

AIDL communication exchange parameters serializing and deserialing them. I suppose Map cannot be serialized because it depends by its implementation. If your keys/values types will be fixed, maybe you could overclassing Map with a your Parcelable type and then you have to write your custom writeToParcel readFromPArcel